# “ benefits of ” vs. “ benefits to”

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I encountered an expression:

> key **benefits *to*** using [something]

To my mind the version below would sound more natural:

> key **benefits *of*** using [something]

Are both versions correct? Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: I think I'll leave the phrases in my question as they are - in his answer tchrist highlighted other prepositions that might be used with benefits, so "benefits to [something]" is quite legitimate (benefits to the community), whereas "benefits to using [something]" doesn't feel very natural

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, both do seem to be used, with *benefits of* being more common than *benefits to*, and [apparently always has been](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=benefits+of%2Cbenefits+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=5&share=).

[image: benefit of-vs-to]

You might also compare actual published instances of [*benefits to using*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22benefits+to+using%22&btnG=Search&tbs=bks%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1982%2Ccd_max%3A2008&lr=lang_en) versus those of [*benefits of using*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22benefits+of+using%22&btnG=Search&tbs=bks%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1982%2Ccd_max%3A2008&lr=lang_en) to see whether you can pull out any major nuance.

However, I think you **probably** want *benefit of* here.  The OED has this to say about it:

> **3**. a. Advantage, profit, good. (The ordinary sense.) ***for the benefit of***: for the advantage of, on behalf of. ***to take benefit of*** (a thing): to take advantage of, avail oneself of. ***benefit of the doubt***: see **doubt** *sb*.

Thinking about the difference between:

- a benefit to the community
- a benefit of the community
- a benefit for the community
- a benefit from the community

It seems like *to* and *of* go different directions.  A benefit *to* society is different from enjoying the benefit *of* society.  Similarly, *benefit of clergy* and *benefit to clergy* are quite different.

But I also think you are right that some people may use this interchangeably; I do not find anything wrong with either of your two formulations, but if push came to shove, I’d likely opt for the *of* version.