# Why do we say "There is a benefit to..." not "There is a benefit of"?

Tags: prepositions

At least in my dialect of english (so-called American Standard) the latter would sound strange. Does anyone experience it this way? Of course, "The benefit of..." is acceptable. The same is true of (dis)advantage. Are there any other examples like this?

[update] a closely [related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106773/benefits-of-vs-benefits-to) is mentioned in the comments. The degree of relatedness is discussed in the comments below. Some answers to this question might not serve as an answer to that one. Some answers given to that one have relevance here. The question specifically came up because I was asked to proofread something containing the specific latter construction, which I was inclined to argue was not valid. "There is a benefit of eating rice," for example, does not seem "correct" to me.

Also, my title has been validly criticized. "Why do we" might better be phrased as "In what way do these mean different things? What meanings do they share and not share?" I hope that is more acceptable.

Comment: Closely related: [“ benefits of ” vs. “ benefits to”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106773/benefits-of-vs-benefits-to).

Comment: @StoneyB - I think it makes sense.

Comment: There are multiple problems with this question. Any question starting with "Why do we say ..." is either unanswerable (other than "Because English is weird like that") or invites personal opinion. There's not enough information provided to exclude such obvious constructions as "there is a benefit of the doubt". "Does anyone experience it this way" invites personal opinion. "Are there any other examples" invites a list. For all this reasons, and the lack of an answer after three long years, it should be closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“ benefits of ” vs. “ benefits to”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106773/benefits-of-vs-benefits-to)

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica Questions of usage always contain heavy dollops of opinion--nonetheless people do have opinions and comparing them can be informative . I was not trying to open a proscriptivist/descriptivist debate. I just wanted to know if my perception would be considered a minority or majority view. Certain constructions I deem as strange nonetheless are used frequently in certain varieties of English, but IMHO this does not invalidate my opinion as to their aptness in my variety of English. Why did you say my question started with "Why do we say?"  Time is relative.

Comment: @user14006 and CJDennis That's a good link, but no, not quite. I am asking specifically about the singular form in the latter. The benefit of eating rice, the benefits of eating rice and the benefits to eating rice are all ok and of similar meaningh to me. But for me "there is a benefit of eating rice" sounds specifically ungrammatical, and if it has meaning, I feel its meaning would be different. I am trying to see if anyone else has this impression, and if so, what underlying grammatical rules, etc. might be involved. My question was intentionally open, rather than overly specific, though.

Comment: I just actually read the link that was given in the comments above and see that (the title threw me off) one reply does mention the singular case and what I was talking about. Though still does not answer my particular question exactly, it is by all means relevant. I don't know if it is possible/recommended to move my question to that question or not in this case, but if it should be moved that is okay by me after all.  I agree the questions are at the least part of the same constellation.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica I just re-read my title. Yes, I said "Why do we say..." I think I must have put it that way for space constraints, but even so, I think the question is valid shorthand for my actual question, which addresses your concern about it being a request for opinions or unanswerable. I think it is possibly answerable to some extent, and opinions can be informed and valuable. But your observation has merit as well. Of course English(language) is fungible, yet even though there is no definitive answer, we understand the difference between sense and nonsense.

Comment: 'There is a benefit to (or in) [eating rice, say]' means [eating rice, etc] is beneficial. // 'The benefit of eating rice is that ...' spells out what the benefit of eating rice is (I'd have thought there were several). //// 'There is a benefit of eating rice' really needs to go on to mention the benefit.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, good point. the "word" benefit in your last example is really a different word that just uses the same letters. What do you think about "There is a benefit of eating rice." though?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth oops, looks like you edited out the part of comment I referred to. I was mentioning the example "There is a benefit for eating rice", meaning a gov't subsidy.

Comment: It's far better with padding. 'The third benefit of eating rice regarding our health is ...' sounds far more idiomatic (and can be found on the internet). Standalone, it sounds unnatural, as 'benefit to' is so common. // I was going beyond the question there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for your replies. You also inserted the answer (in your first comment, prior to my first reply to you) to my question (benefit of). How would you go on and mention the benefit in a sentence? "There is a benefit of eating rice such as its low fat?" Would that work for you? Is that what you mean? I am on the fence. I guess "There is" is integral to my question. You are right about padding, and "benefit to" dominates. Is there anyone who accepts "There is a benefit of..", because that is actually what I was tempted to argue against.

Comment: I'd use 'The benefits of eating rice are its cheapness, its carbohydrate content, its low fat ....'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think so too.. The benefits of..cheapness, ..."  I can't thank you enough for your thoughtful observations. You've covered the space around it nicely. If it were an answer, I would accept it -- but i have the nagging feeling someone is preparing a counterargument. Apologies to the meta-gods for the extended discussion, but the iron was hot.